# C# receiving TCP/IP multisocket server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I have developed a server with a socket open which, each second, receives an int number. This is my code.

```
private void runServer()
    {
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 16001);
        tcpListener.Start();
        updateUI("Buscando clientes");

        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread tcpHandlerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(tcpHandler));
            tcpHandlerThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

private void tcpHandler(object client)
    {
        TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream = mClient.GetStream();
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
        updateUI("HR: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message) + "\n");
        stream.Close();
        mClient.Close();
    }
```

I want to have 4 devices connected at the same time sending that **int** data, but with this code, the server stops receiving some seconds, then receives all together. Can u say me the changes I have to do to listen 4 sockets and get my int data each second?

**EDIT:**

Thats the code that calls runServer()

```
 private void cmdServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (serverStatus)
        {
            //El servidor está iniciado, así que paramos el servidor
            cmdServer.Text = "Run server";
            updateUI("Server Stopped.");
            serverStatus = false;
            cmbEventos.Enabled = true;
            lblTituloEvento.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            lblTituloEvento.Text = "Selecciona el evento y pulsa Iniciar Servidor";
        }
        else
        {
            Thread tcpServerRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(runServer));
            tcpServerRunThread.Start();
            updateUI("Server is now running.");
            cmdServer.Text = "Stop server";
            serverStatus = true;
            cmbEventos.Enabled = false;
            lblTituloEvento.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            lblTituloEvento.Text = "Server " + cmbEventos.Text + " Online";
            int numConvert;
            bool resultado = int.TryParse(cmbEventos.SelectedValue.ToString(), out numConvert);
            idEvento = numConvert;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:

I added the loop as usr said:

```
private void tcpHandler(object client)
    {
        TcpClient mClient = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream = mClient.GetStream();
        StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] message = new byte[1024];
        int numberOfBytesRead;

        // Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
        do
        {
            numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
            myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(message, 0, numberOfBytesRead));
        }
        while (stream.DataAvailable);

        //Old Reading
        //stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);

        String messageRec = myCompleteMessage.ToString();
        String[] auxMessage = messageRec.Split(new Char[] { '-' });
        switch (auxMessage[0])
        {
            case "HR":
                //HR command received
                updateUI("HR: " + auxMessage[1] + "\n");
                break;
        }


        stream.Close();
        mClient.Close();
    }
```

Comment: You need async processing.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the button Click method with the thread start. See the Edit

Comment: You should consider using asynchronous sockets, using a thread per client is **wrong**

Comment: The thread opening only runs on the click event of the button CmdServer. Then  the method of the thread - runServer() - listens for connections. It is only one thread on all the application. Instead, can you show me a great example of asynchronous sockets which fits my objective please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the return value from Read. It tells you how many bytes were actually received, the minimum of which is one.

Usually, you need to read in a loop.

TCP provides a boundaryless stream of bytes. If you want to send messages you need to invent some kind of protocol that does this. For example, length prefixed protobuf is a good idea.

Besides that your design is capable of handling multiple clients. It should work.

> You need async processing.

No, that has nothing to do with the problem. Using threads for sockets is just fine.

Comment: I edited the post to show the Button who calls runServer() in a thread. Sorry, I forgot to include it in the post.

Comment: His design might be capable of handling multiple clients, but it's **not** fit for it. He is not able to handle multiple clients that access the same data, shares data or interacts with each other, considering there's no thread-safety and if he does implement locking, there's a high possibility of dead locks.

Comment: @Bauss none of these concerns were visible in the initial version of the quesiton. The code was just fine. He *was* able to handle multiple clients. One thread per client works just fine in case there are not too many such clients  (here: 4).

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal is your question answered? Not sure what point you are trying to make with that edit.

Comment: @usr no, It is not, I edited to show how I open a thread with the listener because everybody was comeenting I was needing threads or asynchronos procesing. As you commented, I am using the Read value on the message var, and updating my UI with updateUI(). Could you tell me how to fit my code for my 4 connections please?

Comment: @ProgramadorAdagal did you make the code changes that I recommended? I have a feeling that you didn't do all of them. Post the new code.; You have now asked for async IO code but that does not solve your problem. Do not ask for random things that you do not understand. Try to understand the problem instead.

Comment: @usr I am trying to do with all your answers right now (I am a rookie in C#), but I have several doubts. I explain: I have realized then on my loop I open a new thread (as Bauss said before), then in my thread I open the connection, receive the data with Read on message var and update my UI. Thats wrong as all say, but cannot imagine how to do it without starting a thread in the loop. Otherwise, I am changing the buffer for accepting 6 chars (the 6 I need: 2 for the command code, 1 for the separator and 3 for the value).

Comment: The accept loop is completely ok. No need to change anything. Bauss was adamant but did not explain his opinion. Starting a thread per client *will* work and it's not the problem you are having.

Comment: @usr I made the changes. Now my doubt is how to close the threads and dispose the objects contained in them.

Comment: Just wrap the client and the stream in using blocks. The read loop is still broken because DataAvailable might be zero when more data will eventually arrive. You need to stop reading based on content. When you can tell that everything has arrived. That depends on the protocol.